# How to detect the application is terminated in application when it is managed by `forever`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

Is there a way to detect the application is terminated *in the application* when the application is managed by `foreever`?

It is well known that we can grab the `process` event (`exit` / `SIGINT` / `SIGTERM` / `SIGHUP`) when the application is booted by node manually in a terminal. However, there's no cited event caught at all when the application is started by `forever`.

for example, the concerning application is named `app.js`:

1. if we run `node app.js`, we can catch event `SIGINT` when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.
   however,
2. if we run `forever start app.js`, we can **NOT** catch such events.

thus, how can we detect the application is terminated *in the application* when it is booted by `forever` ?

Comment: `ps aux | grep app.js`

Comment: @RPM I need to know it in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this node package https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever-monitor

Comment: forever-monitor is good, but it can only monitor child process, instead of the running process.